# Retrieve list of objects based on a key value constraint

Tags: elasticsearch

I have object instance index in ES 6.2 which I can query like this:

```
POST /_search 

{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {
                    "match": {
                        "instanceId" : "I001"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

and receive a particular instance query result:

```
{
  "took": 1,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 15,
    "successful": 15,
    "skipped": 0,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 1,
    "max_score": 5.7745514,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "instance",
        "_type": "searchinstance",
        "_id": "I001",
        "_score": 5.7745514,
        "_source": {
          "name": "someInstance",
          "uuid": "18fab6a6-0fc9-428e-ad60-a13a6a43e0ea",
          "id": "I001",
          "createdAt": 1559140971501,
          "completedAt": 1559140988024,
          "modifiedAt": 1559140988028,
          "description": "my description",
          "instanceId": "I001",
          "status": null,
          "attributes": [
            {
              "name": "response.result",
              "value": "0"
            },
            {
              "name": "response.value",
              "value": "123"
            }
          ],
          "createdBy": null
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

How do I query all of such instances (i.e. just list of instanceId values) having `"attributes.name": "response.result"` and `"attributes.value": "0"`?

I've been trying to combine query_string, match, wildcard and nested query types but still not being successful. It seems that the issue is specifying path to attributes structure correctly. When POSTing:

```
{
    "query": {
        "nested": {
            "path": "attributes", 
            "query": {
              "bool": {
                "must": [ 
                  {
                    "match": {
                      "attributes.name": "response.result"
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "match": {
                      "attributes.value": "0"
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I receive a failure reason

```
{
  "type": "query_shard_exception",
  "reason": "failed to create query: {...}",
  "index_uuid": "8Sr_2jvsRvqGmDjK71SFsw",
  "index": ".kibana",
  "caused_by": {
    "type": "illegal_state_exception",
    "reason": "[nested] failed to find nested object under path [attributes]"
  }
}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Elasticsearch doesn't have a dedicated array type. In fact, any field of any type is treated as array of values. So assuming your `attributes` field is of object type you can query it just as you would normally do for single object, for example:

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [ 
                {
                    "match": {
                        "attributes.name": "response.result"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "match": {
                        "attributes.value": "0"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately, for some reason, this approach does not work (returns zero hits). Is it possible that my index configuration or ES data repository (using spring-data-jest-3.2.0) is wrong?

Comment: @VladimirKoutny ideally you would want your `name` and `value` fields to be of type `keyword` and then use `term` query instead of `match`. Try updating your question with `GET instance/_mapping` info so that we have a better idea of what is going on for this type. 

Also, if you do need to find documents specific name-value pairs then you do indeed require `attributes` to be of nested type instead of being flattened like Elasticsearch usually does for objects. So you will need to create new type with propper mapping and reindex your objects.

Comment: Hi, this mapping get response seems to be ok, right?
`{
    "instance": {
        "mappings": {
            "searchinstance": {
                "properties": {
                    "attributes": {
                        "type": "nested",
                        "properties": {
                            "name": {
                                "type": "keyword"
                            },
                            "value": {
                                "type": "text"
                            }
                        }
                    },
...`

Comment: @VladimirKoutny it does look ok. Are you sure you are querying this index? Because otherwise `[nested] failed to find nested object under path [attributes]` doesn't make much sense. Does `GET instance/_search { "query": { "match_all": {} } }` return those documents?

Comment: Putting instance path into the URI resource did the trick. Thank you!